# Always visible save / cancel elements inside DIV?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm rendering DIV elements as rows. The edit template for this form is quite long. I have a small save and cancel button on the top left of the edit template DIV. I would like the command buttons to be visible and scroll down when they are scrolled outside of the visible region of the edit DIV.

The whole thing is wrapped in a fixed-height element with overflow: auto.

Hopefully this makes sense. I've thrown together a Fiddle to help illustrate what I'm talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/fJ55D/3/

jQuery is A-OK.

**EDIT:** A twist! My grid is in another element. I didn't think it would cause problems but it may be *the* problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor the amount of the page that is being scrolled and add/remove a class that will fix the element to the viewport:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var $save = $('.save'),
        off   = $save.attr('data-offset') || $save.offset().top;

    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= off) {
        $save.not('.fixed').attr('data-offset', $save.offset().top).addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $save.filter('.fixed').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fJ55D/4/

Here is a jsfiddle forked off of your "fixed-height-scrolling-div" example: http://jsfiddle.net/fJ55D/5/

Comment: Thanks. The "save" span still breaks out below but maybe I can go from here.

Comment: @OrangeKid What do you mean by "breaks out?"

Comment: If you scroll beyond the edit row, "save" is still visible on top of the other read-only items. http://jsfiddle.net/fJ55D/6/ (With extra rows at bottom to illustrate.)

Answer (score 0):

This might do it.  (Depends on your other code)

```
.save{
    position:fixed;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fJ55D/1/

Comment: Thanks. That worked for that example but I forgot to mention the fact that this whole thing is in a fixed-height scrolling DIV. http://jsfiddle.net/fJ55D/3/